# xts: how to keep control of data types after as.xts?

Tags: r, xts, lubridate

Consider the following dataframe

```
time <-c('2016-04-13 23:07:45','2016-04-13 23:07:55','2016-04-13 23:08:45','2016-04-13 23:08:45'
         ,'2016-04-13 23:08:45','2016-04-13 23:07:50','2016-04-13 23:07:51')
group <-c('A','A','A','B','B','B','B')
value<- c(5,10,2,2,NA,1,4)
df=data.frame(time,group,value)

> df
                 time group value
1 2016-04-13 23:07:45     A     5
2 2016-04-13 23:07:55     A    10
3 2016-04-13 23:08:45     A     2
4 2016-04-13 23:08:45     B     2
5 2016-04-13 23:08:45     B    NA
6 2016-04-13 23:07:50     B     1
7 2016-04-13 23:07:51     B     4
```

Note the missing value row `5`. Now I convert to `xts` after using `lubridate` to convert my timestamps to proper Posix types.

```
> df$time = ymd_hms(df$time)
> df<-as.xts(df,order.by=df$time)
> df
                    time                  group value
2016-04-13 23:07:45 "2016-04-13 23:07:45" "A"   " 5" 
2016-04-13 23:07:50 "2016-04-13 23:07:50" "B"   " 1" 
2016-04-13 23:07:51 "2016-04-13 23:07:51" "B"   " 4" 
2016-04-13 23:07:55 "2016-04-13 23:07:55" "A"   "10" 
2016-04-13 23:08:45 "2016-04-13 23:08:45" "A"   " 2" 
2016-04-13 23:08:45 "2016-04-13 23:08:45" "B"   " 2" 
2016-04-13 23:08:45 "2016-04-13 23:08:45" "B"   NA
```

and my nice `numeric` column `value` is now a `character`!

How can I avoid that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The underlying xts object for the data is a matrix which can be numeric or character type, but not both (unlike data.frame which is a list where each column can be of any atomic type in R).  A rough check of seeing this happen is to try this:

```
> as.matrix(df)
     time                  group value
[1,] "2016-04-13 23:07:45" "A"   " 5" 
[2,] "2016-04-13 23:07:55" "A"   "10" 
[3,] "2016-04-13 23:08:45" "A"   " 2" 
[4,] "2016-04-13 23:08:45" "B"   " 2" 
[5,] "2016-04-13 23:08:45" "B"   NA   
[6,] "2016-04-13 23:07:50" "B"   " 1" 
[7,] "2016-04-13 23:07:51" "B"   " 4"
```

which is what `coredata` returns when creating an `xts` object:

```
x.df<- xts(df,order.by=df$time)
> coredata(x.df)
     time                  group value
[1,] "2016-04-13 23:07:45" "A"   " 5" 
[2,] "2016-04-13 23:07:50" "B"   " 1" 
[3,] "2016-04-13 23:07:51" "B"   " 4" 
[4,] "2016-04-13 23:07:55" "A"   "10" 
[5,] "2016-04-13 23:08:45" "A"   " 2" 
[6,] "2016-04-13 23:08:45" "B"   " 2" 
[7,] "2016-04-13 23:08:45" "B"   NA
```

Remove the `time` and `group` columns when creating the xts object to get numeric data as you expect.  You could map the group column types to integers.  You also shouldn't include `time` in the xts object creation for the `x` argument, as your `order.by` is already containing the time information.

e.g.

```
df$group_idx <- as.numeric(as.factor(df$group))
x.df<- xts(df[, c("group_idx", "value")],order.by=df$time)
> x.df
                    group_idx value
2016-04-13 23:07:45         1     5
2016-04-13 23:07:50         2     1
2016-04-13 23:07:51         2     4
2016-04-13 23:07:55         1    10
2016-04-13 23:08:45         1     2
2016-04-13 23:08:45         2     2
2016-04-13 23:08:45         2    NA
```

Comment: thanks for your detailed answer! that is interesting. I am quite new to `xts` (coming from the great `pandas`) but that limitation in `xts` seems to be a big bummer to me. That means we cannot carry information such as `ISIN` codes, `sector names` and other strings. Basically, what can `xts` do that, say, `dplyr` or `data.table` + `lubridate` can't?

Comment: You can store some qualitative information as attributes in the `xts` object.  xts makes subsetting time series data very easy, merging time series data at *different time frequencies* is a breeze with merge and na.locf, TTR functions naturally work with it, and it is fast...  You should check out Jeff Ryan's page on quantmod (google it) to see the true power of xts.

Comment: also I wouldn't typically work with mixing security prices/values in a single xts object.  Use a different xts object for different securities (this may remove your need for a group column)